# zero downtime asp.net deployments and session state problems

Tags: asp.net, deployment, session-state

At work we have a fairly good process for zero-downtime deployments of a busy ASP.NET MVC web site. There's two server groups so we can move traffic over, we write db SP's to be backwards compatible and roll them out in advance. Generally, it works well.

However, one issue has just tripped me up. The last deployment included a lot of code namespace changes.

When the build was deployed it broke existing user sessions because the objects in their session state no longer existed on the new codebase e.g. their session contained App_Code.UserDetails and the site now has a class of X.Y.Z.UserDetails

I understand the problem and why it happened, but what I can't work out is if there's anything that can be done apart from a full site shutdown to ensure there are no active users on the site. Or maybe restarting the state service so everyone gets booted off and has to log in again. Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking this over I've arrived at two possible solutions:

a) Always deploy web site updates with downtime. Keep the site down long enough for all sessions to expire. This is a safe option technically but unacceptable commercially

b) Simulate the problem and look at what can be done address the issue in the exception handler. Although not an ideal end-user experience it may be better to catch SerializationExceptions on session state, and flush the user session. They will have to authenticate again but it's not as bad as a broken session.

A decision I made upfront is that it's going to be difficult to pick up on live session dependencies during development, there are just too many other things to consider.

I will be investigating (b) as it sounds quite feasible.